# Google Static Maps and Driving Directions

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, java-me

I have made a mobile application that use Google static maps to get map from A Position to B Position, and I have also used Google Direction API to get all path direction from A Position to B Position

When I try to send these direction using URL to Google static maps it does not work completely as I can't send a lot of information using URL.

Is there any way to let me send any number of points to be drawing on Google Static Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reading [Google Maps API - Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) which allows you to pass shorter urls by encoding points.

You can test your encoded values by using [Google Maps API - Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)